# Outlets found nil after moving tableviewcell to new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I originally had several `UITableViewCell`s on a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. Then, I moved the `UITableViewCell`s to a new `UITableViewController` I created because I wanted to make them static cells and the only way to make them static was to use them on a `UITableViewController`. However, after I moved, them, although everything was connected and all the cells were set to the right xib files, the app crashed and it said the outlets on the `UITableViewCell`s, like my `UILabel`s, were found nil. I then tried to create brand new `UITableViewCell`s with brand new xib files on the `UITableViewController`, but then I couldn't even connect any outlets for any `UILabel`s or anything else. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this? All my code looks normal and I've been using `UITableView`s for a long time, just never creating static cells before.

Comment: The devil is in the details. What outlets are you referring to? Table view cells aren't owned by their view controler, and so don't normally have outlets to the view controller. You can certainly set up outlets to a custom cell class. You say you couldn't connect the outlets. What outlets, and connect them from where to where?

Comment: @DuncanC The outlets I'm referring to are uitableviewcell objects, such as uilabels or uiswitches that I want to include in the static tableviewcell.

Comment: Expand your question to include the code of your custom UITableViewCell class, as well as a screenshot of the storyboard definition of that cell with the connection inspector. My guess is that when you dragged the cell from one view controller to another the outlet connections were broken.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! In a `UITableViewController` with Static Cells you don't need to create a custom class for the cells and drag your outlets there (what I did); you can just drag your outlets directly onto the `UITableViewController` and it will work there.